# Newborn has a red rash on her chin

Tags: newborn

She's only a few days old and she has been breastfeading regularly.
A rash has developed on her chin which doesn't seem to bother her too much.

How should it be treated (or perhaps left alone)?

Comment: My daughter has developed a rash on her forehead, eyelids and cheeks two days ago. I have consulted it with a pediatrician, she says it's nothing harmful and should go away on it's own. Looks [like this](http://i.imgur.com/zeMt9QK.jpg).

Comment: Perhaps a call in to the Pediatrician?  We have to be careful about medical advice online, and especially without specifics about size, shape and color of the patches in the offending rash, even a doctor would have trouble being certain whether the rash was an average friction rash, or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My babies used to get that from moisture that collected (milk, sweat, and saliva) on the chin during breastfeeding, combined with friction. You can try patting the chin dry during breastfeeding or putting a soft cloth between chin and breast during feeds. Left alone, it will probably clear on its own, though, as baby ages and gets better at feeding.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some extra baby-specific moisturizer for a few days, if the pediatrician gives you the all-clear.  Our son had ridiculously sensitive skin his first year or so, and only daily lotioning kept it under control.